# Convert unstructured txt to csv for use with dataframe later

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text blob with the format below -

```
05-19 14:55:41.978 10219 12976 13024 I A: AA BB -110, D -200
05-19 14:55:42.078 10219 12976 13024 I A: AA BB -110, D -200
05-19 14:55:42.712 10219 12976 13024 I A: AA BB -110, D -91
05-19 14:55:42.729 10219 12976 13024 I A: AA BB -110, D -91
05-19 14:55:43.781 10219 12976 13024 I A: AA BB -110, D -91
05-19 14:55:43.781 10219 12976 13024 I A: System is overloaded so call is failing.
05-19 14:55:46.719 10219 12976 13024 I A: Executing CALL to end point, withValidation:true, Fallback:false
05-19 14:55:47.304 10219 12976 13024 I A: AA BB -110, D -85
05-19 14:55:47.304 10219 12976 13024 I A: System is overloaded so call is failing.
05-19 14:55:47.308  root   882 26792 E B  : Socket failed to connect: Network is unreachable
05-19 14:55:47.310  root   882 26793 E B  : Socket failed to connect: Network is unreachable
05-19 14:55:47.311  root   882 26792 W B  : Validation failed
05-19 14:55:47.312  root   882 26794 E B  : Socket failed to connect: Network is unreachable
```

I want to convert this to CSV so that I can read it with pandas later but I don't want to lose context in this conversion. My desired CSV needs to be like -

```
05-19,14:55:41.978,10219,12976,13024,I,A:,AA BB -110, D -200
05-19,14:55:42.078,10219,12976,13024,I,A:,AA BB -110, D -200
05-19,14:55:42.712,10219,12976,13024,I,A:,AA BB -110, D -91
05-19,14:55:42.729,10219,12976,13024,I,A:,AA BB -110, D -91
05-19,14:55:43.781,10219,12976,13024,I,A:,AA BB -110, D -91
05-19,14:55:43.781,10219,12976,13024,I,A:,System is overloaded so call is failing.
05-19,14:55:46.719,10219,12976,13024,I,A:,Executing CALL to end point, withValidation:true, Fallback:false
05-19,14:55:47.312,root,882,26794,E,B  :,Socket failed to connect: Network is unreachable``
```

If replace the `\s` in each line with `,` I will lose context since I want to keep the elements in the last column together. Looking for suggestions for this problem.

Comment: you should maybe divide each line in to 2 lines, then build a structure for the first part and second part and merge them back together.

Comment: Good idea. I tried it but the actual data is more complicated so will go with some of the other suggested approaches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a job for regex:

```py
import re

pattern = r'^(\S*)\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*)\s*(.*?:)?\s*(.*)'
lines = re.findall(pattern, text, re.M)
new_text = ''.join(','.join(line) + '\n' for line in lines)

with open('new_file.csv', 'w') as file:
    file.write(new_text)
```

That regex is long, but mostly it's just these parts:

- `(\S*)` a word (not spaces)
- `\s*` space(s)
- `(.*?:)?` optional span of characters leading to and including a `:`
- `(.*)` everything else on the line

I strategically used `*` instead of `+` on most of the groups so that it will match more generously if certain fields are missing, but if you want a stricter match then use this regex pattern instead:

```py
pattern = r'^(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(.+?:)?\s+(.+)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `read_fwf()` you can read this pandas and then use `to_csv()`

```
data='''05-19 14:55:41.978 10219 12976 13024 I A: AA BB -110, D -200
05-19 14:55:42.078 10219 12976 13024 I A: AA BB -110, D -200
05-19 14:55:42.712 10219 12976 13024 I A: AA BB -110, D -91
05-19 14:55:42.729 10219 12976 13024 I A: AA BB -110, D -91
05-19 14:55:43.781 10219 12976 13024 I A: AA BB -110, D -91
05-19 14:55:43.781 10219 12976 13024 I A: System is overloaded so call is failing.
05-19 14:55:46.719 10219 12976 13024 I A: Executing CALL to end point, withValidation:true, Fallback:false
05-19 14:55:47.304 10219 12976 13024 I A: AA BB -110, D -85
05-19 14:55:47.304 10219 12976 13024 I A: System is overloaded so call is failing.
05-19 14:55:47.308  root   882 26792 E B  : Socket failed to connect: Network is unreachable
05-19 14:55:47.310  root   882 26793 E B  : Socket failed to connect: Network is unreachable
05-19 14:55:47.311  root   882 26792 W B  : Validation failed
05-19 14:55:47.312  root   882 26794 E B  : Socket failed to connect: Network is unreachable'''

import io
df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(data), colspecs=[(0,5),(6,18),(19,24),(25,30),(31,36),(37,38),(39,200)], header=None)
df[[6,7]] = df[6].str.split(':', 1, expand=True) # split on first : only
df[6] = df[6].apply(lambda x: x+':') # add : back in
df.to_csv('temp.csv', header=None, index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there always the same number of columns in this same format? You can use `re.sub()` to replace the first n occurences in each line.

```
re.sub('\s',',',str,n) # where str is each individual line from the file, and n is the number of times to replace.
```